# div box-shadow on iPad

Tags: html, ios, ipad, css

I am currently developing a touch optimized web app. Part of the concept design includes ease of navigation, so i have designed some nice looking div's that have a 'click' or 'touch' event that look pretty when you touch it.

This works great on a computer web browser and an android browser, but when I use it on Safari on an iPad it does not display a shadow. All my syntax seems right so all i can conclude is that it is a bug or not supported.

My question is: Has anyone come across this issue and discovered a fix or work around?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8WF8/1/)

CSS:

```
div.touch-button:active {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

div.touch-button {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
After a lot of stress and messing around, and giving up. I came across the issue whilst trying to resolve another issue.

It was related to the viewport settings.

NOT CORRECT:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

CORRECT:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />`

Comment: your issue was related to box shadow not appearing on safari and what you changed here would disable the zoom and keep it to the original size it was designed.

Comment: Rider is right. You might wanna try this instead: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">`. I found this work-around while trying to solve a zoom problem. Which it didn't, but it did cure the iOS box-shadow problem in Landscape view in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use box shadow before -moz-box-shadow and -webkit-box-shadow.
This solved the same issue for me in the past.

```
div.touch-button {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;    
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: Sorry that doesn't seem to have worked. It appears that there is a slight shadow (approx 1px), i have to really squint to see it. Increasing the shadow doesn't seem to fix it either.

Answer (score 0):

Use -webkit-appearance: none; for overriding default, try this..

```
div.touch-button {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

div.touch-button:active {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```